# There isn't ntdll.mak file in the OpenSSL ms folder. Where can I find this file?

Tags: compiler-errors, openssl, nmake

I am going to compile Openssl using "`nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`".
 But I got errors, that's because there isn't the ntdll.mak file in the ms folder of the Openssl source.
Where can I find the ntdll.mak file?

Comment: What is the version you;re trying to build?